# Error No font or default font set in mpdf 6.1

Tags: html, codeigniter, pdf, mozilla, mpdf

I'm using codeigneiter in my system and mpdf 6.1 to generate pdf. When i'm adding new font in ttfont, then i get eror "**No font or default font set!**", code in my html to print:

```
$mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8','A4','');
$mpdf->fontDir = './third_party/mPDF/ttfont/'; /* location to save new font */
$mpdf->fontdata['ampleSoft'] = array(
        'R' => "ampleSoft-bold.ttf",
        'B' => "AmpleSoft-Medium.ttf",
);

$mpdf->SetFont('ampleSoft');
```

And in file config_fonts i'm adding new code:

```
'ampleSoft' => array(
        'R' => 'AmpleSoft-Medium.ttf',
        'B' => 'ampleSoft-bold.ttf'
    )
```

What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fontDir` variable is not available in mPDF 6.x. Define the path in `_MPDF_TTFONTPATH` constant. You may need to duplicate used font files from the distribution to your custom directory.

https://mpdf.github.io/fonts-languages/fonts-in-mpdf-6-x.html

Comment: so where i can find `_MPDF_TTFONTPATH` ?

Comment: just define a constant of this name before including mpdf.

Comment: I've updated the docs, hope that helps https://mpdf.github.io/fonts-languages/fonts-in-mpdf-6-x.html#specify-custom-font-directory